# Linear programming formulation of if-then constraint

Tags: linear-programming

Consider an LP for which you want to add the restriction that

> Only if $x_1\geq 3$ then $x_2$ and $x_3$ are allowed to be larger than $0$; otherwise $x_2$ and $x_3$ are $0$.

Demonstrate how to formulate this.

Comment: With such a constraint, it is no longer linear.

Comment: Hello, Daan. For help on how to ask homework questions (as this question appears to be), please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) post.

Comment: It is for my thesis i have data I need to formulate into my LP model but have trouble with defining the restrictions

Comment: As others have pointed out, this simply is not linear. It cannot be formulated as an LP. If, however, you are willing to accept *binary* variables into your model, then it can be.

Comment: You could try a solver for Satisfiability Modulo Theories (SMT) like [Z3](http://rise4fun.com/z3).  Your background theory would be linear arithmetic, but then you can use arbitrary Boolean combinations of linear constraints.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do this and preserve this being a linear programming problem is to split it into two problems. In one, have the constraints $x_1<3$ and $x_2 = x_3 = 0$. In the other, have the constraints $x_1 \geq 3$, $x_2\geq 0$ and $x_3 \geq 0$.

Comment: Then you get if x1<3+MY then x2[>=]M(1-Y) and x2=x3 and Y=binairy

Comment: then you have to add another Y = 0/1 constraint for the fact that x2 can also be >=0, how does that work then?

Comment: It might help to give a bit more of the setup you are using. With the type of linear programming problems I've taught, the constraints I've mentioned are easy to setup and work with for a 3 variable problem.

Comment: Indeed you need to solve two problems (or use binary variables). However, $x_1<3$ does not define a closed set. The original problem is ill-posed in the sense that an optimal solution may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Let the column vectors $c^T=(c_1,c_2,c_3, \ldots, c_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $b^T=(b_1,b_2,b_3, \ldots, b_m)\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and a matrix $A=(A_{ij})_{\substack{1\leq i\leq m\\ 1\leq j\leq n}}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. Consider a typical linear programming problem
$$
\min_{x\in \mathscr{F}} c^Tx 
\hspace{1cm} or \hspace{1cm}
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & c^Tx\\
\mbox{such that} & x\in \mathscr{F}
\end{array}
\hspace{1cm} or \hspace{1cm}
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & c^Tx\\
\mbox{such that} & Ax\geq b\\
\end{array}
$$
for $\mathscr{F}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:Ax\geq b \}$. For your restriction consider the sets
$$
B=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\left| \begin{array}{l} x_1\geq 3 \\ x_2> 0\\ x_3> 0 \end{array}\right.\right\}
\mbox{ and }
C=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\left| \begin{array}{l} x_1< 3 \\ x_2= 0\\ x_3= 0 \end{array}\right.\right\}.
$$ 
So by adding the above restrictions we have
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & c^Tx\\
\mbox{such that} & x\in \mathscr{F} \\
                 & x\in (B\cup C)
\end{array}
\hspace{0.5cm} or \hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & c^Tx\\
\mbox{such that} & x\in (B\cup C)\cap \mathscr{F} 
\end{array}
$$
But $B\cup C=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x_1\geq 0, x_2\geq 0\}$. Then your linear programming problem comes to be
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & c^Tx\\
\mbox{such that} & x\in (B\cup C)\cap \mathscr{F} 
\end{array}
$$
Which in block matrix notation comes to be written as
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & c^Tx\\
\mbox{ such that} & 
\left\lgroup 
\begin{array}{c}  
A             \\
\tilde{A}     
\end{array}
\right\rgroup
\left\lgroup
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{array}
\right\rgroup \geq 
\left\lgroup
\begin{array}{c}  
b\\
0\\
0     
\end{array}
\right\rgroup
\end{array}
$$
for 
$$
\tilde{A}=
\left\lgroup
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&\ldots &0\\
0&1&0&\ldots &0\\
\end{matrix}
\right\rgroup_{2\times n}
$$

Comment: $A\cup B\neq\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x_1\geq 0, x_2\geq 0\}$